# How to remove yellow borders from editable content in the Aloha Editor javascript plugin?

Tags: jquery, aloha-editor

I'm struggling with customizing the Aloha Editor.  I'd like to remove the yellow borders around the editable content:

[image]

In Github, the same question was asked, and the answer given was,

> the highlight plugin shows the user editable areas when he moves the
>   mouse. If you don’t want to use it just don’t include. Or do your own
>   highlight plugin...

However, I don't believe that I'm including the highlight plugin.  My Aloha settings looks like this:

```
Aloha.settings = {
    locale: 'en',
    plugins: {
        format: {
            config: [  'b', 'i', 'sub', 'sup', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6' ],
            editables : {
                '#title'    : [ ] // no formatting allowed for title
            }
        }
    },
    sidebar: {
        disabled: true
    }
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that `HighlightEditables` plugin is disabled then you're probably facing this [bug](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/839). As suggested by `issue opener` you may try removing `!important` from CSS:

```
.aloha-editable-active, .aloha-editable-active[contenteditable=true]:focus {
       outline: #80B5F2 solid 5px !important;
}
```

---

**Update**:

As a reply to @Marcin's concern, please make sure that you **don't** have `common/highlighteditables` in `data-aloha-plugins` attribute of your [Aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.org/guides/plugins.html) `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="javascripts/aloha/aloha.js"
  data-aloha-plugins="common/format, common/link"> // HERE
</script>
```

Here is the corresponding [configuration](http://www.aloha-editor.org/guides/plugin_highlighteditables.html):

```
Aloha.settings.plugins: {
    highlighteditables: {
        config: [ 'highlight' ],

        editables: {
            '#one': [ 'highlight' ],
            '#two': [ ] // do not show visual effect for this editable
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ugly trick that does not disable the highlighting, but hides it and it may stop to work in next versions, if some plugin developer changes the class name...

Comment: @MarcinSkórzewski, This is a bug if you have the plugin disabled and they'll fix it. See the link above.

Comment: I see. @clone45 probably has chosen the plugin list in the `data-aloha-plugins` attribute.

Comment: @MarcinSkórzewski, let him review your answer. Maybe you are right. But I recommended him to do this trick if _he is sure_ the plugin is disabled.

Comment: Hi guys, I switched over to using a different javascript package for inline editing.  Thanks for all your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You should just not to load the plugin responsible for highlighting of the editables. Its name is "common/highlighteditables" and you customize which plugin you want to use with array in settings: `Aloha.settings.plugins.load`. Now, you are including it because you do not specify the plugin list and the default one is loaded.